# Power BI - Matrix Drill-down Causes Upper Level in Hierarchy to Disappear

Tags: matrix, azure-sql-database, powerbi, hierarchy

I am working with a client new to Power BI, and they complain that when drilling down to the next level, the level above "disappears" showing only the parent of the drill-down records, as shown here:

Top Level Shows All Records

[image: Top Level Shows All Records]

After drill-down, we see the next level down, but *only* the parent record at the level above:

Here, the lower drill-down records appear, but only their parent appears from the level above.

[image: Here, the lower drill-down records appear, but only their parent appears from the level above.]

My client would like the hierarchy to still display the parent levels while expanding only the one child level they are interested in viewing the detail for.  I know that entire levels can be expanded at once, but is there a way I can create a matrix that allows the behavior the client is looking for?

Can I drill-down in a Power BI matrix to a lower level while leaving the level above displayed in its entirety?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Expand to the next level, instead of drill down. This should do the work. Try it and let me know if this is the case.

You may find this useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-matrix-visual

Comment: This does not do the trick, rather it expands *all* at the next level when all I want is to expand a single level leaving the parent level untouched.